# HTML Show picture that fits screen

Tags: html

I have the followin code, that shows a picture:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>* {margin:0;padding:0;}</style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
<center>
<script type='text/javascript'><!--//<![CDATA[
   var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'URL1':'URL2');
   var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
   if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
   document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
   document.write ("?zoneid=1");
   document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
   if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
   document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
   document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
   if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
   if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
   if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
   document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
//]]>--></script><noscript><a href='URL3' target='_blank'><img src='URL4' border='0' alt=''/></a></noscript>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And I want to make that the picture fits the screen, and I have tried to put width="100%" in the img, in the a href... but it is always the same size.

How can I make it?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't understand what the javascript does?

Comment: I know that this code shows a picture, I don't care how it works, I only want to make it bigger.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `backstretch` jquery. `Backstretch` is a jQuery plugin that allows you to add a dynamically-resized background image to any page. The image will stretch to fit the page, and will automatically resize as the window size changes.

Here is an example:

> http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is place the image as background to an element and make the element cover the whole screen. (And you don't need any JS for that, only HTML and CSS.)
Example:

HTML

```
<a id="imgA" href='http://www.stackoverflow.com' target='_blank' /a>
```

CSS

```
#imgA {
    background-image: url(<url_to_img>);

    /* Make the image cover the whole element area */
    background-size: 100%;

    /* Make the element occupy the whole window */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/q99rv/).

(Also, note that if you don't need the link-functionality, you can replace the `<a>` element with a `<div>`.)

Answer (score 0):

> as per docs u can try by adding background-cover to fit image on screen

```
#img
{
background:url(img.jpg);
background-size:cover;
}
```